# Do you get paid in USD directly if you work as a blockchain developer/engineer in the US?

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain

I want to know if I become a solidity/web3/blockchain developer or engineer in the US, do companies in the US or companies in general pay you in USD directly (not through USDT, USDC, or some other crypto)? If not, can I request the company I am interviewing pay me in USD directly for this job? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it depends on the company. Some companies will pay directly in USD. Some others will offer you the option to receive the pay in USDT or USD, partially or completely.

I'm a blockchain developer and I work for a company that offers me to receive payment in USDT or USD, either or, not partially. I receive it in USD because it's easier for me to manage at the moment.

I think all, or at least most, are able to use the traditional methods to pay if you request it.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. I know this question is closed now, but do you know if blockchain developer interview consists if coding questions? If so, what resources can I use to best prepare for them? Thank you.

Comment: Hey! The blockchain technology and development ecosystem is very, very complex and critical. One mistake and millions of dollars could be lost, by forking the chain, accidentally locking funds forever, etc.
This is why usually they test your technical skills very thoroughly during an interview. Yes, they usually require a high level of algorithms and data structure knowledge, several years of general software development, communication, team work, etc. Some companies higher developers that don't have much experience, but they have blockchain senior to help and guide them.

Comment: To improve your algorithms and data structure skills, you could try solving code problems on sites like leetcode, hackerran, codewars, codility, etc. There are many resources on youtube to visually understand better algorithms and data structures. You could simple search for them. 
For smart contract development and security, you could start solving challenges on The Ethernaut site https://ethernaut.openzeppelin.com/
Read books about cryptography, maybe get some courses in Udemy, practice and study a lot, etc.

Comment: Thank you Jeremy!